# Python pandas - display the value with the highest number of records in a columns for each distinct value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table similar to this but with around 60,000, rows where each number is a code for a string.
I need to get the most popular color for the 2 most popular vehicle types.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Vehicle_type':[1 ,5 ,2 ,5 ,5 ,3 ,5 ,2 ,3 ,1 ,4 ,5 ,4 ,3 ,4 ,1 ,2 ,1], 
                    'Color':        [10,11,10,10,11,14,11,10,13,12,14,15,12,13,14,12,11,14]})
```

To find the 2 most popular vehicle types I used this:

```
data['Vehicle_type'].value_counts().head(2)
```

and the output is:

```
5    5
1    4
Name: Vehicle_type, dtype: int64
```

To get from that dataframe all the colors for the 2 most popular vehicle types I used:

```
newdata = data['Vehicle_type'].apply(lambda x: x == 5 or x==1)
data[newdata]
```

output:

```
Vehicle_type    Color
1                10
5                11
5                10
5                11
5                11
1                12
5                15
1                12
1                14
```

An I got stuck here. I have tried different approaches with .groupby() but I could't make it.
The output I would like should be something like this:

```
Vehicle_type    Color
   5             11
   1             12
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to groupby over vehicle type and then aggregate the mode for each group:

```
data.groupby('Vehicle_type')['Color'].agg(pd.Series.mode)

Vehicle_type
1    12
2    10
3    13
4    14
5    11
Name: Color, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution but it works.

After getting your data you can add a count column which is always 1, then sum this to get the count for each:

```py
data['count'] = 1

data = data.groupby(['Vehicle_type','Color']).sum()
```

This will give you a dataframe that has all vehicle type/color combinations and the count of them in the count column.

If you want to export the data, I usually call `data.reset_index()` to display everything a little neater.

EDIT: re-read your question and realized you also asked for the max. Call the `reset_index()` and then `data[data['count'] == data['count'].max()]` to get the vehicle type/color with the most counts.